# Using new Azure dotnet SDK for ElasticPool size

Tags: .net, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-elasticpool

I'm trying to use the new Azure dotnet SDK for managing the size of our pool.

Using the following code I can return some of the pool details:

```
ResourceIdentifier id = new ResourceIdentifier(idStr);
ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
ElasticPoolResource ep = client.GetElasticPoolResource(id);
ep = ep.Get();
```

But I'm then struggling how to read or update any of the values. Is anyone aware of any examples of how to use this new SDK with ElasticPools specifically as I'm not getting very far using the standard documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm then struggling how to read or update any of the values. Is anyone aware of any examples of how to use this new SDK with ElasticPools specifically as I'm not getting very far using the standard documentation.

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models.maxsizerangecapability?view=azure-dotnet), you can get the size of elastic pool using `MaxSizeRangeCapability Class` which includes following properties:

- LogSize
- MaxValue
- MinValue
- ScaleSize

Alternatively, you can use [Elastic Pools - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2020-08-01-preview/elastic-pools/create-or-update)

You can refer to these examples: [ElasticPoolResource.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/46a3b95e0c82307d09714801e226fe4fdb6dd6ec/sdk/sqlmanagement/Azure.ResourceManager.Sql/src/Generated/ElasticPoolResource.cs), [MaxSizeRangeCapability.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/4162f6fa2445b2127468b9cfd080f01c9da88eba/sdk/sqlmanagement/Azure.ResourceManager.Sql/src/Generated/Models/MaxSizeRangeCapability.cs) and [ElasticPoolPerformanceLevelCapability.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/b106eec3a2c4ccf4f9e67966fa4cc80abbfe7244/sdk/sqlmanagement/Azure.ResourceManager.Sql/src/Generated/Models/ElasticPoolPerformanceLevelCapability.cs)